# Big O running time for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis

Here's the code for the algorithm:

```
Foo(n)
   lcm = 1
   for i = 2 to n
       lcm = lcm*i/Euclid(lcm,i)
return lcm
```

The running time of `Euclid`$(a, b)$ is given as $O(\log(\min(a, b)))$

So the running time of the for loop will be $O(n)$, so would this be the final running time? or do I have to take the $O(\log(\min(a, b)))$ into account as well?

Comment: What do you think?  What have you tried?  We expect you to make a serious effort before asking.  You'll need to do your own exercises; there is a reason why they are assigned to you -- the way you learn is by doing the exercise yourself, not by asking someone else to solve it for you.

Comment: @D.W. What the OP has thought and tried is included in the question. It's short but it's a short exercise. They have a specific question about their attempt, which is what we generally ask for. I don't think this falls under "Unclear what you're asking."

Comment: I think it's more likely that we can help the poster if they show their reasoning.  Is "So it will be O(n)" a guess, or how'd they get to that answer?  Showing the details of the calculation or reasoning they used to get O(n) would make this question more readily answerable.

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: Note also [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/844#844) on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The running time for the loop will be
$$ O\left(\sum_{i=2}^n (1+\log \min(\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,i-1),i))\right). $$
The $1$ takes care of the arithmetic operations beyond GCD, and the other term is the running time of GCD, as given to your. The arguments to GCD are `lcm` and `i`. The value of `lcm` at iteration $i$ is $\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,i-1)$, explaining the complete formula.

We can upper bound this sum by
$$ O\left(\sum_{i=2}^n (1 + \log i)\right) \leq O\left(\sum_{i=2}^n (1 + \log n)\right) = O(n\log n). $$